# Trying to customise an Elgg database query

Tags: elgg

I've been trying to customise the block user plugin in order to create a 2 way block, however, I am running into a problem when trying to tweak the lib/functions.php in event manager.

I am essentially just getting the list of blocked users and then trying to put a "NOT EXISTS" clause in before the event list is returned via the $entities_options query array. I'm farily new to the DB querying side of things in Elgg so could use some help in getting this right.

```
// GET ARRAY OF BLOCKED USERS

$users = lee_framework_get_options(elgg_get_plugin_user_setting('blockuser_get', lee_loggedin_user_guid, 'blockuser'));
$blocked_user_array = array();
foreach($users as $user)

{
    $blocked_guid = get_user_by_username($user)->guid; 
    $blocked_user_array[] = $blocked_guid;

    $entities_options['owner_guids'] != $blocked_guid; // This is just to indicate what I am trying to achieve!

}
```

I believe I need to use the JOINS / WHERES clauses, as used in the rest of the page but am struggling to find and use the correct field names. eg.

```
$entities_options['joins'][] = "JOIN " . elgg_get_config("dbprefix") . "entity_relationships e_ra ON e.guid = e_ra.guid_one";
$entities_options['wheres'][] = "(e_ra.guid_two IN (" . implode(", ", $friends_guids) . "))";
```

Any advice on this would be very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, this was solved using the following code placed in the functions.php file of event manager:

```
// GET ARRAY OF BLOCKED USERS

$blocked_users = lee_framework_get_options(elgg_get_plugin_user_setting('blockuser_get', lee_loggedin_user_guid, 'blockuser'));
$blocked_user_array = array();

foreach($blocked_users as $user) {

$blocked_user_array[] = get_user_by_username($user)->guid;

$entities_options['joins'][] = "JOIN " . elgg_get_config("dbprefix") . "metadata md on e.guid = md.entity_guid";
$entities_options['wheres'][] = "md.owner_guid != " . get_user_by_username($user)->guid;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to model this using Elgg relationships. Eg UserA blocks UserB would be one relationship. Elgg has an API for creating and querying based on these that should make this easier.